# Oddity: Determinant of Skew-Symmetric $n\times n$ Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A \in M_{n×n}(\mathbb{R})$ be a skew-symmetric matrix, i.e., $A^t = −A$. Prove that if $n$ is odd, then $\det{A} = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Amire's answer is certainly the most straightforward way.

Another way to see it is that the eigenvalues of a skew-symmetric matrix are necessarily imaginary. Being a real matrix, they have to appear in conjugate pairs. If the dimension is odd, then one eigenvalue is also real, and so it has to be zero. As the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, the result follows.

Comment: nice and instructive , thanks

Comment: @MartinArgerami This is Jacobi's Theorem isn't it?

Comment: It is. But I don't know if this is the canonical way of proving it. Amire's way is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Hint : remember that $\det A= \det A^t$ and that $\det kA= k^n \det A$.